# RegExp is also blocking UK when .UK is ment to be blocked

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation

this is my RegExp

```
    function wordInString(s, word){
          return new RegExp( '\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
    }
var about=jQuery('#compdesi').val();
            var education=jQuery('#educationhistory').val();

            if((wordInString(about, '@')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.com')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.co')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.org')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.net')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.info')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.au')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.uk')==true) || (wordInString(about, '.ac')==true))
            {
                alert("You can not enter website, email or phone number in about");
                return false;   
            }
```

this is blocking Both UK,com and .UK .com what M i doing wrong !

m using test as text :-

was born into a family of artists in mial in UK. he  had a deep impact on his painting. now regularly  in Africa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like dystroy says, except you need to double escape, try this line instead:

```
if ((wordInString(about, '@')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.com')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.co')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.org')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.net')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.info')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.au')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.uk')) 
    || (wordInString(about, '\\.ac')))
```

Answer (score 2):

`.` in a regex means "any character".

Use `"\\.uk"`

Answer (score 0):

Change this function to:

```
function wordInString(s, word){
      return new RegExp( '\\b\\\\' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
}
```